# How to bind AJAX loaded elements to JQuery plugins with on() function

Tags: jquery

I am using a JQuery plugin datepicker that allows me to set options e.g. default date, format, minimum date etc.

**Here is the code**

```
$(".standardDatePicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: new Date(_currentTime.getFullYear(), _currentTime.getMonth(), _currentTime.getDate(), 1)
});
```

I am loading content via Ajax into a modal, but am then trying to bind those elements that have been inserted into the DOM with a call to the datepicker plugin.

The following code has worked fine on other code but i cant find a way to use it with plugins, is this even possible without modifying the plugin?

**What I have tried**

```
$("document.standardDatePicker").on(datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: new Date(_currentTime.getFullYear(), _currentTime.getMonth(), _currentTime.getDate(), 1)
}));
```

Comment: most of jquery plugins do not support event delegation. you need to re-attach the plugin after adding element on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done with the `on()` method of jquery with the following "hack":

```
$('body').on('focus',".standardDatePicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(_currentTime.getFullYear(), _currentTime.getMonth(), _currentTime.getDate(), 1)
    });
});​
```

You bind the `focus` listener on the `body` of your document. When the event fires upon one of the descendants being `.standardDatePicker` it will handle the function adding the datePicker.

When putting focus on the element it will automatically add the datePicker.

Datepicker is clever enough to check if it is already created or not on the element so no overhead or any other issues.

Another option is ofcourse also adding the datepicker when dynamically creating the element.

For example:

```
var newElement = $('<input>');

// insert what you want to add to the element (classes etc.)
newElement.attr('type','text');
// etc
newElement.datePicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(_currentTime.getFullYear(), _currentTime.getMonth(), _currentTime.getDate(), 1)
});
document.append(newElement);
```

**Dynamic options example:**

For example you add options when you add the element to the DOM:

```
$('document').append('<input type="text" class=".standardDatePicker" data-months="2" data-format="dd-mm-YY">');
$('document').append('<input type="text" class=".standardDatePicker" data-months="1" data-format="dd/mm/YY">');

$('body').on('focus',".standardDatePicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: $(this).data('format'),
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: $(this).data('months'),
        minDate: new Date(_currentTime.getFullYear(), _currentTime.getMonth(), _currentTime.getDate(), 1)
    });
});​
```

Comment: Nice, But what about the options? I need them to differentiate between different types of datepicker.

Comment: Either make sure you can put the logic in the eventHandler or take option 2 and add the datePicker when you also add the element.  For example create multiple datePicker classes and let the eventHandler put on different options based on the class. I will add an example.

Answer (score 1):

*I am loading content via Ajax into a modal, but am then trying to bind those elements that have been inserted into the DOM with a call to the datepicker plugin.*

You can make use of `.ajaxComplete()` method:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $(".standardDatePicker").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date(_currentTime.getFullYear(), _currentTime.getMonth(), _currentTime.getDate(), 1)
    });
});
```

---

Seen your comment, you can make a function and you can call it:

```
var dateInit = function(){
    $(".standardDatePicker").datepicker()    
};

$(document).ajaxComplete(dateInit);
```

now you can call this function on doc ready to initialize.

Comment: This makes the most sense, but doesn't that mean i will have to duplicate my code to include both ajax and non-ajax logic? e.g. the datepicker method will be called twice - once before ajax is loaded and once after. So i will have to include the same logic twice, once with ajaxcomplete() and once without? in my case thats a lot of duplication.

Comment: You can call a function which initializes the date picker.

Comment: Ah this is clever. It means i can have a separate Ajax file for the application i only initialize when i need to. Thanks Jai.

Comment: and even you can pass some option object for different datepickers this way as passing those in the function's args.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to attach the event to a higher element in the DOM.

Do

```
$(document).on('focus',".standardDatePicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: new Date(_currentTime.getFullYear(), _currentTime.getMonth(), _currentTime.getDate(), 1)
 });
});​
```

Comment: Your answer has absolutely no correlation with the piece of code you copy pasted.  It isn't a `change` event  and doesn't reset anything.